# Android Studios Alarm Manager app closed

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have been fighting with this for quite a while now, I am using alarm manager to schedule an alarm, I have a receiver declared in my manifest file. The alarm and the receiver work as intended while the app is running or in the background, I am unable to get my alarms to fire after the app has been closed by the user. I'm essentially just trying to have local notifications in my application. None of the other "answers" here have been much help. Is it possible to have a local notification fire when the app has been closed?

```
public static void writtenGoalsNotification(Context context) {

    final int _id = 15;

    pref = context.getSharedPreferences("userpref", 0);

    Notification notification = getNotification("Don't forget to write your daily goals!", context, "none", "Goals");
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);

    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, "written goals notification");
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, _id, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Integer hour = pref.getInt(NotificationKeys.Goals.ReminderTime.hour, 10);
    Integer minute = pref.getInt(NotificationKeys.Goals.ReminderTime.minute, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);

}
```

Here is my receiver,

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

    startWakefulService(context, intent);

    WakeLocker.acquire(context);
    WakeLocker.release();

}
}
```

This is in my manifest,

```
  <receiver
        android:name=".Controllers.NotificationReceiver"
    </receiver>
```

Comment: show error logs

Comment: Could I get something more descriptive? The code isn't generating any errors, the notification happens correctly while the app is running or in the background. The problem is that once the app has been closed, either the alarm or the receiver is destroyed.

Comment: i misunderstood the issue. accept my apologies. i think you need to extend a boardcast receiver.... ive never worked with a wakeful broadcast receiver. hopefully someone else can chime in to help you out though.

Comment: try using IntentService instead of BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Or try adding `android:exported="true"` in `receiver` tags.

Comment: I had the same problem, what I have done that. Initiate the service override onTaskRemoved() then again set the alarm. @SeanCalkins

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast receiver is deprecated in API level 26.
The main reason you do not get alram received is because the process of App you are using is finished and cleared if there is low memory in device. Instead you should use service so that it has higher priority.
So for this I suggest you to use BroadcastReceiver class instead of WakeupBroadcastReceiver because android docs says this-
          (It is generally not safe to start a service from the receipt of a broadcast, because you don't have any guarantees that your app is in the foreground at this point and thus allowed to do so.)

Thus your process of setting alram may be destroyed. So use BroadcastReceiver.
In manifest do this

```
<receiver
        android:name=".NotificationReceiver"
    </receiver>
```